# Convert URL subfolders to parameters with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

So I have the following stucture:

```
https://www.example.com

/index.html
/css
/images
/something
/else/with_subdirs
```

In each folder there could be index.html file

I want to convert all

```
http://www.example.com/dir1/subdir1?random_list_of_params
```

requests to

```
https://wwww.example.com/index.html?d=dir1&sd=subdir1&random_list_of_params
```

if dir1 or subdir1 do not exist.

This should be dome up to 3 levels deep aka

```
http://www.example.com/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/?random_list_of_params

https://wwww.example.com/index.html?d=dir1&sd=subdir1&sdd=subdir2&random_list_of_params
```

Please note dir1, subdi1 and subdir2 vary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For implying https to your all requests.
RewriteCond HTTPS !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

####For urls http://localhost:80/singh/singh1/singh2?testblabla
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.html?d=$1&sd=$2&sdd=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

##For urls http://localhost:80/singh/singh1?testblabla
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.html?d=$1&sd=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

##For urls http://localhost:80/singh?testblabla
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.html?d=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```